# JavaScript file only works or loads inside Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript file which is used in two user controls. The JavaScript is loaded by use of

```
          src="../../Scripts/UI/DateScript.js">
```

The script tag is added at the end of the markup and not at the beginning on both user control. This is because some of the functions need to access values in a few textboxes, which won't exist until the controls are loaded and populated.

Everything works inside Visual Studio 2010 development server, but if run the application from IIS again using Visual Studio if get a Microsoft JScript runtime error myfunction is undefined.

I have tried changing the path to ~/Scripts/UI/DateScript.js or just /Scripts/UI/DateScript.js. Further, I have tried moving the script tag to the master page and adding it towards the end of the markup, but again this hasn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by file structure

Comment: Use your browser's debugging tool (for example, press F12 in Chrome) and check the path of your JavaScript file. I believe you will see what the problem is.

Comment: It is a web application, where it will run in IE8. Using IE Development tool kit, when I call the page it shows the script tag and the current file as ~/Scripts/UI/DateScript.js. However, in the console page of tool kit it shows an error on one of functions as undefined.

Comment: try  <script language="javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>Scripts/UI/DateScript.js"></script>, Hop eit will worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using ResolveUrl around the file path